# Why are the movement arrows of the Unity game object offset from it?

Tags: 3d, unity3d-editor

[image]

How to fix it?
I need this for the correct rotation of this object

Comment: without knowing any Unity: My bet is that these arrows are centered at the point (x,y,z)=(0,0,0) in object coordinates, but the center of your object is not there.

Comment: their coordinates are -7.968692 -7.023793 -3.285539 how do i move them to the model?

Answer (score 0):

that's a late answer and not sure but if your object has a child like Main Camera, movement arrows may appear in its position.